# Is there updated code for olFolder.Folders.Add function?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-2010

i have the below code here that makes a new folder in outlook.
this code worked but the system got updated with microsoft proplus.
and now an error occurs.

```
Sub Create_Folder()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Data")
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

olFolder.Folders.Add ("Saved Data") ' run time error cannot create folder occures here 

Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Saved Data")
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the parenthesis? They do not belong there anyway, as it's not being used as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the exact error?  You *will* get an error if the folder already exists. You need to test if the folder exists first:

```
on error resume next
err.Clear
set subFolder = olFolder.Folders("NDR")
if err.Number <> 0 Then
  set subFolder = olFolder.Folders.Add("NDR")
End If
```